# Running query on collection items in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql

So I am stumped, and just cannot seem to grasp what is going on. I have a function that takes an array of orders.

```
var collection = [{ordernumber: 1, href: 'FileDetails.aspx?FileId=1234'}, 
                  {ordernumber: 2, href: 'FileDetails.aspx?FileId=1478'}];
var OrdersListToImport = [];

function loopOrders(collection, callback) {
  for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    console.log('processing order #: ' + collection[i].ordernumber);
    var answersReturned = 0;
    db.needsImported(collection[i].ordernumber, function(answer) {
      if (answer) {
        OrdersListToImport.push(collection[i]);
        //console.log(collection[i]);
      }
      if (++answersReturned == collection.length) {
        callback();
      }

    });
  }

}
```

NeedsImported function as follows:

```
needsImported: function(ordernumber, callback) {
    pool.query('Select controlnumber From orders Where ordernumber = ?', [ordernumber], function(err, result) {
      if (!err) {
        if (result.length == 0) {
          callback(true);
        }
        else {
          callback(false);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

When inside the callback function of db.needsImported, collection[i] becomes undefined. It was driving me mad, so i made a little sample file to see if there was a reason I couldn't access an argument from inside a callback function. It works as expected, only pushing even numbers. here is the sample:

```
var nums = [];
var collection = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

displayValue(collection, function() {

});
console.log(nums);

function displayValue(col, callback) {
  for(var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    sleep(col[i] * 500, function() {
      console.log('Count: ' + col[i]);
      if (col[i] % 2 == 0) {
        nums.push(col[i]);
      }
    });
    callback();
  }
}

function sleep(time, callback) {
  var stop = new Date().getTime();
  while(new Date().getTime() < stop + time) {
      ;
  }
  callback();
}
```

I hope someone can help me to understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might see more clearly what the problem is if you were to `console.log(i)` in the spot where you expect `collection[i]` to not be undefined.

What's going on in your for loop is you're iterating through your array and firing off multiple asynchronous tasks. When the loop is finished, the value of `i` is 2. `i` is a closed variable accessible to your callbacks, but remember the asynchronous timing here, your `needsImported` callbacks are all getting invoked *after* your for loop has completed, so naturally, `collection[2]` is undefined. To fix it you could just get rid of the index and use `Array.forEach` instead:

```
function loopOrders(collection, callback) {
    var answersReturned = 0;
    collection.forEach(function(item, index) {
        needsImported(item.ordernumber, function(answer) {
            console.log('index:', index);
            if (answer) {
                OrdersListToImport.push(item);
            }
            if (++answersReturned == collection.length) {
                callback();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Note also that if you do need to keep track of the index in your callback, you can receive it as the second parameter in your `forEach` callback as I've done above.

One more note :) There's a significant flaw in this code:

```
needsImported: function(ordernumber, callback) {
    pool.query('Select controlnumber From orders Where ordernumber = ?', [ordernumber], function(err, result) {
      if (!err) {
        if (result.length == 0) {
          callback(true);
        }
        else {
          callback(false);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

If an `err` does occur, you're ignoring it, but worse than that, you're not invoking the callback. Confusing bugs will emerge from this. It's common practice in node to serve an err var as the first argument of a callback, so in a success scenario you would do this `callback(null, true)`.

Comment: This fixed the issue. So, I originally thought if its going so fast that I might get a callback for 2, but im actually now on i = 5. I thought that using a forEach would mess it up, because its checking one item, but it is now on the next item, so I may end up pushing the incorrect item into the array. Can you tell me why a forEach item wont push the incorrect item if it will push the incorrect "i"? Or point me in the direction so I can learn about it?

Comment: Your callbacks aren't "going so fast" as to be racing against the completion of your for loop. You misunderstand how the node event loop works and the fact that your code is executing on a single thread. Your for loop will deterministically finish iterating before any of your callbacks get invoked. Think of it like an event queue. Your for loop is occurring because it was triggered by event A. During its course of execution it pushes two more pending events B and C onto this queue. The code path of event A must finish entirely to completion before B or C will ever get popped off the stack.

Comment: And I'm not quire sure what you mean by forEach pushing the incorrect item.

Comment: I meant the entire body of the forEach runs before the next iteration of the forEach, so there is no chance of pushing the incorrect item into an array.

Comment: I think I understand your confusion now. The `item` variable you get in each `forEach` callback has the same name but they are each *different instances*, they all exist in separate function invocations, therefore separate scopes.

Furthermore, for each iteratin of `forEach`, a new closure is created for the `needsImported` callback. Each closure has access to its corresponding `item` instance. There's no risk of one iteration pushing the `item` variable from a different iteration, they exist in different scopes.